# Get current theme in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have an issue with this code:

```
$currentDesign = Mage::getDesign()->setAllGetOld(array(
        'package' => Mage::getStoreConfig('design/package/name', $this->getStoreId()),
    ));
```

I need to convert this code to magento 2 but I don't know what function or code I need to use, please someone suggest to me, thanks.